# Is there a way in CSS to calculate line height from em?

Tags: css, fonts, html-table

Let's say I want an img to be the same height as a line of text.  Is there some way to set this up.  My first thought was something like this:

```
<table>
    <td>
        <img src="pict.png" style="height: 1em"/>
        <img src="pict.png" style="height: 1em"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        The text<br/>
        The second line<br/>
    </td>
</table>
```

However, with that example, the height of the picture is less than the line.   After a few lines the difference becomes very noticeable.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Also, it looks like for my font 1.15 em is about equal to the line height.  Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: 1 em is the width of a lower case m in whatever font face you are using. You can also use en and ex values, which are lowercase n and x widths respectively, FYI.

Comment: @metagrapher What I really need is the height of a line, to use that as the height of the img. Sebastian Patane Masuelli had me set the line-height, which means I don't hav to calculate or know the line-height at run time, because it is already set.

Comment: I still have yet to understand how a line height can be set in em (based on what I explained above.)  I suppose it just uses the typical default of 16px in that case.  Seems confusing/unclear to me.

Comment: I guess what I meant was that it's best to set it to an explicit 16px rather than let the browser decide what the default is, which is usually but not always 16px.  1em may be set to 12px on some machines/browsers and that would break your implementation, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your images are the same height as the line of text in your example.  ([see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/UcJ8L/)).
if it looks differently in your project, you can try setting `line-height: 1em` in your table, and make sure that `font-size: 1em`.

as for part two:
i hope this image helps explain the relationship between line-height and font-size: 
[image]

Comment: cool, you can also apply the `vertical-align` css declaration to your image styles, (i.e. `vertical-align: middle` will center the image vertically in the line of text.

Comment: <table style="line-height: 1em">
    <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height: 1em"/><br/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="height: 1em"/><br/>
    </td>
    <td >
        The text<br/>
        The second line<br/>
    </td>
</table>

Comment: I will check out the vertical-align.  That sounds like another good idea.

Comment: nice, i added an image explaining the font-size/line-height relationship, i hope it helps make sense of the second part of your question

Comment: Thank you.   I wish I knew the line-height to font ratio, however, I see now it can change.

Comment: Sadly, I have to be able to change the font-size.

Comment: if you set the font-size in the parent element (in this case the table), the images in the child element inherit that size as 1em

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: I want to calulate the line height server-side before I even write the HTML, if possible.

Comment: I don't want to adjust the img size for each image after the page is displayed.

Comment: i don't think you need javascript for this.

Comment: @Sebastian, if you really think that, please provide the CSS solution. I'm interested.

Comment: @simshaun: just posted an answer, i think it solves it with only css.

Comment: cool.  I wasn't being sarcastic.  I really did want to see.  Upvoted!

Comment: totally! i didn't mean to sound snarky with my comment either! we're all here to learn, no?